# Multiple MIDI sounds with MusicDeviceMIDIEvent

Tags: ios

I am creating MIDI sounds with MusicDeviceMIDIEvent and it's perfectly fine, I use some aupreset files I've created. One for each instrument.

My code is basically the example from apple: [LoadPresetDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Listings/LoadPresetDemo_Classes_MainViewController_m.html). All I use is:

```
- (void)loadPreset:(id)sender instrumentName:(const char *)instrumentName {
   NSString *presetURL1 = [NSString stringWithCString:instrumentName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:presetURL1 ofType:@"aupreset"];
   NSURL *presetURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
   if (presetURL) {
      NSLog(@"Attempting to load preset '%@'\n", [presetURL description]);
   }
   else {
      NSLog(@"COULD NOT GET PRESET PATH!");
   }

   [self loadSynthFromPresetURL: presetURL];
}
```

To load my aupreset file, then:

```
- (void) noteOn:(id)sender midiNumber:(int)midiNumber {

   UInt32 noteNum = midiNumber;
   UInt32 onVelocity = 127;
   UInt32 noteCommand =     kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;

   OSStatus result = noErr;
   require_noerr (result = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (self.samplerUnit, noteCommand, noteNum, onVelocity, 0), logTheError);

logTheError:
   if (result != noErr) NSLog (@"Unable to start playing the low note. Error code: %d '%.4s'\n", (int) result, (const char *)&result);
}
```

to play the note of the previously loaded aupreset, and:

```
- (void) noteOff:(id)sender midiNumber:(int)midiNumber
```

when I want it to stop.

Now I would like to play one note of each instrument simultaneously. What is the easiest way of doing this?